# Why std::queue is not releasing memory when swap() is used?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue

I ran into some weird memory issue with `std::queue`. When the queue (wrapped in another object) is shared by several threads, the memory used to store elements is never released, even when the queue is empty and a workaround with `swap()` is used. I wonder why?
Here is my queue wrapper:

```
template<typename T>
class thread_safe_queue {
public:
thread_safe_queue() {};
thread_safe_queue(const thread_safe_queue& orig) = delete;

void push(T item){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(_m);
    q.push(item);
    _signal.notify_one();
};

T wait_and_pop(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(_m);
    _signal.wait(lk, [this]{ return !q.empty(); });
    auto res = q.front();
    q.pop();
    return res;
};
T wait_for_and_pop(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(_m);
    if(_signal.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::seconds(1), [this]{ return      !q.empty(); })){
        T res = q.front();
        q.pop();
        return res;
    }
    else{
        return T();
    }
};

long unsigned int size(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(_m);
    return q.size();
}
void clear(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(_m);
    std::queue<T>().swap(q);
}

private:
    std::mutex _m;
    std::condition_variable _signal;
    std::queue<T> q;
};
```

Sample producer-consumer program:

```
void producer_thread(thread_safe_queue<string> * q){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            q->push("ABCDEFG");
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    }
    q->clear();
}

void consumer_thread(thread_safe_queue<string> * q){
    while(true){
        string a = q->wait_for_and_pop();
        if(a == ""){
            cout << "Clearing from consumer" << endl;
            q->clear();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(100));
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   thread_safe_queue<string> q1;
   std::thread t1(&consumer_thread, &q1);
   std::thread t2(&producer_thread, &q1);
   t2.join();
   cout << "Clearing from main" << endl;
   q1.clear();
   t1.join();

   return 0;
}
```

I tried to release memory with `clear()` method from all three threads, but the memory is still not released (according to htop and pmap). I'm running this program in CentOS7.

Edit: `clear()` do release memory if all the code is running in single thread.

Comment: The object might be returning memory to the C or C++ runtime, but that probably doesn't return memory to the OS so htop or pmap won't notice any change.

Comment: @MichaelBurr This seams like a memory leak to me. I tried with larger data set, the process consumed 2/3GB of RAM happily and did not release it ever.

Answer (score 0):

Processes rarely return memory to the OS.  Sometimes OS has a "I need address space" message it can send to a process, but in a 64 bit address space it is unlikely to be needed.

Measuring how much memory a process currently has allocated via the OS level memory usage doesn't work.

The C/C++ runtime takes memory returned, and stores it for later allocation use, rather than bugging the OS again.

Comment: so are you saying that tools like pmap, top, htop has no way to measure the memory used by a process? Seems weird as I was under impression that these tools are quite reliable. Anyhow, if I run all the code in main (single thread) the memore is released by `clear()` method.

Comment: @Hitman_99 They measure the memory the process has asked for from the OS, which is not the same as the memory allocated within C or C++.